# TFS Web Extension for editing JSON

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-web-access

We have some JSON configuration files, which we store in our TFS 2015 repo. And, some non-developers want to edit those JSON files, through the TFS web interface. I've been asked to build a custom UI around that editing experience. In short, a form wrapped around a JSON file.

So, is there a way to do this through "TFS web extensions"? Of the scant background and samples I can find, it all related to TFS Work Items. But, I want to build a form for an actual source-controlled file. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible using the [VSTS extensions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/overview). 
This will only be available on premise in one of the updates next year though.
The current extension model that you have on premise will fall away in lieu of the new model.

Comment: Thanks, Niel -- I hadn't seen this info, and it looks really promising. We have on-premise TFS 2015. So, let me see if I understand you correctly. VSTS extensions are available in VS online now, and we be available on-premise next year. The current on-premise extension model is going away, and anyway it will not support what I want to do. Did I restate that correctly?

Comment: in a nutshell yes, you can obviously edit the files directly, but if you would like any intelligent form or end-user experience I will suggest the new extension model. You can try the current web access extensions on-prem but it is not going to be nearly as easy and - as I mentioned - will fall away for the new model.